# Does Forcing UEFI Installation of Ubuntu risk making Windows 10 unbootable?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi, windows-10

That is what the Ubuntu installation wizard says. I am using a Thinkpad X220. I upgraded from Windows 7, and then "reset" (is that just reformatting?) Windows 10.

Here's an image: [http://imgur.com/gallery/TmXf0Wq/new](https://imgur.com/gallery/TmXf0Wq/new)

Comment: You have to switch to Legacy BIOS in your UEFI BIOS.

Comment: Will that prevent or force Windows 10 to be unbootable?

Comment: Prevent. Beacuse if you use UEFI in 1 operating system and legacy in another, it's obvious you have to be switching to legacy bios and then uefi and then to legacy and uefi and etc. for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows is booting in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, then the relevant firmware options are already set appropriately. Don't change them. What's required is to boot the Ubuntu installation medium in the same mode. This is usually done by selecting the correct option in the firmware's boot menu -- namely, the entry for the medium that *lacks* the string "UEFI" to boot in BIOS mode, or the one that includes that string to boot in EFI mode. Your message should only appear in an EFI-mode boot when the installer *thinks* that Windows is booting in BIOS mode.

Note that the installer might have been thrown off by something and be mis-reporting the boot mode. I recommend you check the partition table type code of the Windows *boot* disk with `parted`, as in:

```
sudo parted /dev/sda print
```

Look for the line that begins `Partition Table` -- it will be identified as `gpt` (GPT) or `msdos` (MBR). A GPT disk denotes an EFI-mode boot of Windows and an MBR disk denotes a BIOS-mode boot of Windows. If your computer has multiple disks, check them all, and if they vary, figure out from which one Windows is booting.